# Requesting data of 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I want to let users 'mark' tickets for later use.

So I created a table 'marked'.

All tickets are located in the table 'ticketdata'.

I have the following query to request all tickets for the logged in account:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticketdata WHERE member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM users WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']).") AND status <='3'");
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to let users 'mark' a ticket.

What I have done is create a mysql table (marked) with the following columns:

```
id, member_id, ticketid, active.
```

So now is the question how to execute both queries in order to get the 'marked' tickets. I tried the following query:

EDIT: this is returning ALL results of the specific `member_id` in `ticketdata`, but I only need tickets that are listed in tbl 'marked'.

```
$select = mysql_query("select a.title, a.discription, a.supportername, a.reportername, a.member_id FROM ticketdata a, marked b WHERE a.member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM users WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']).") AND b.active ='1'");
```

Unfortunatly with my basic mysql knowledge I am unable to get this query working.

Is there someone who can help me out ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Learn about JOINs, you want to join the two tables (probably both on `ticketid` and `member_id`).

Comment: - EDITED request

Comment: for start You can read this good article about JOIN types - http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/ with SQL examples

Comment: Now busy trying the examples of your website

Comment: I am still not able to get the query working after reading the provided website.
I still get all restuls of the 'ticketdata' table

Comment: Tried several examples but still getting all results of table ticketdata. Anyone who can help me out ?

Comment: Let's see one of your `JOIN` attempts.

Comment: $select = mysql_query("select a.title, a.discription, a.supportername, a.reportername, a.member_id FROM ticketdata a, marked b WHERE a.member_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM users WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']).") AND b.active ='1'")

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, I've reformatted it to make it easier to read.  You really should specify the type of join (INNER, LEFT OUTER, etc.) and specify how they are related.

```
SELECT a.title
    ,a.discription
    ,a.supportername
    ,a.reportername
    ,a.member_id
FROM ticketdata a
    INNER JOIN marked b ON b.ticketid = a.ticketid 
    INNER JOIN users u on u.member_id = a.member_id
WHERE u.id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id'])."
    AND b.active = '1'
```